# Dynamic text in print composer from layer attributes

Tags: qgis, print-composer, dynamic-text

I have prepared my page layout in print composer, and in my title i want to generate a dynamic texts which is related to an attribute layer which i have filtered previously.

For example:

I have **layer1**(this layer has only one row after filtering) with attributes **att1,att2,att3**
I want a dynamic in my composer that puts a text label **att1-att2** or just only **att1**

This is a screenshot of my layer and their attributes which from i want to make dynamic text.

[image]

Comment: do you want the field name or the value of the attribut ?

Comment: for the moment i need the value of the attribute, it would be nice even to know how to add layer name, field name or attribute and the possibility to combine different field attribute for example CZ||'-'||CZ_NAME

Comment: have you look into attribute table module under composer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243104/attribute-table-print-composer-columns?rq=1

Comment: or maybe what you need is to make an atlas ?

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I already created an atlas which the coverage layer is the one that i want to extract attribute from, but i don't know the expression which takes attributes of the current atlas feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "text label" object and define an expression with the attribute name inside

for example, if you need the value of CZ_NAME attribute of your coverage layer (the coverage layer is the one you choose as such when activating the atlas settings):

`[%"CZ_NAME"%]`

if you want to concatenate with another attribut value and text use :

`[%concat("CZ" ,'-', "CZ_NAME") %]`

Comment: What about relating to other layer, is it possible?

Comment: happy to help. I am sorry, I don't understand what do you mean exactly, please ask a new question for this specific use case.

Comment: No, its related to the same topic so im not opening another question. What i meant is what if i want to take attribut not from coverage layer but from another layer in the layer panel

Comment: I'm wondering the same as you @ShefqetLULJA. Did you happen to find out?

Comment: You mean, you want to concatenate  attributes from 2 different layers ? you should create join or relation on the QGis layer/project before. Then you wil get attributes on the coverage layer.