# QGIS - layout/ print composer and linking displayed maps

Tags: qgis, sql, print-composer, expression, spatial-statistics

**I wonder if it's possible to display a map in the layout/print composer when another is shown ?**

I have this layer [image]where I've made some statistics with diagrams. It shows the percent of people that are "ok" and "not ok" inside of a specific county.

I want to display each diagram based on the counties with the atlas generator. I've already achieved that. Moreover, each county contains many cities and I want to show their statistics on the same page of the atlas.
[image: (here the attribute table)]

To show you the result that I would like to achieve I've made this example. Let's say that the page shows the statistics for the Sicario county (in red is what is supposed to be show). Below the item "variation  by city " I would like to have the statistics for the 3 cities that belong to this county: Trapani, Palerme and Catane.
[image]

**Is ther anay way to linked my first diagram with the display of the statistics by cities with some condition ? **

Like `if "Carte 3 " (which is the view of the diagram) show Sicario then in "Variation by city" put the cities statistics that belongs to Sicario county`

It's very complex...

Comment: You might search on QGIS Atlas dynamic text.  For instance look at the answer to this stackexchange thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259726/dynamic-text-in-print-composer-from-layer-attributes

Comment: Reading the lonked tutorial should give you some pointer https://anitagraser.com/2016/10/15/qgis-atlas-tutorial-material-design/